# Change background of header on scroll with jquery - change back to default color when you scroll back up

Tags: jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

I want my header to change back to its original color if it's less than 600px?

Was thinking about using a switch statement, but don't know that wld work with jquery.

I'm practicing Jquery atm.

```
  $(window).on("scroll",function(){

  if($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
   $(".header").animate({backgroundColor: "#fff" },800);
    $(".header").animate({color: "#000000" },500);
  }

 else {
   $(".header").animate({backgroundColor: "#000000" },800);
   $(".header").animate({color: "#fff" },500);
 }

});
```

Comment: I'm using a jquery plugin UI btw. The code doesnt work at all with the else statement included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you might not see the animation as you scroll is because there's a large queue of animations building up as the scrolling happens.

The solution is to use the [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop any animation currently happening and run the one you want. So change your code to:

```
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $(".header").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#fff", color: "#000000" },800);
    } else {
        $(".header").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#000000", color: "#fff" },800);
    }
});
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpbjknwz/1/)

Comment: That only slowly changes the color of the h1 element that have inside of the header. It does nothing to the background-color of the header?

Comment: Yes - that was because now we're stopping the animation, it stops the background change straight away and runs the color change. I've updated my answer so both changes happen in the same call and included a link to JSFiddle demonstrating the fix